# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException Jenkins pipeline not working

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Installed Jenkins on the new EC2 server, done the same thing before but running into build error as follows

```
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: pipeline for 
class: groovy.lang.Binding
at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
```

have done the same setup before but never got this error.

Comment: Did you install the declarative pipeline support?

Comment: Hey @JoergS , worked fine now. So I was working on Ubuntu Instance and after launching new EC2. Did not do "sudo apt-get update" . Straight away installed Jenkins. I guess that was the Issue. Now its working fine. Thanks